# Could aquatic aliens use bubbles in microscopes?

Tags: technology, ocean, microscopic

In the subsurface oceans of a fundamentally Europa-like moon, (covered in ice, but with an interior warmed by tidal heating etc.) a race of sapient aliens has evolved. These aliens are very interested in where filter-feeding organisms obtain their nutrients, but need a way to find out. The problem is, living underwater as they do, they cannot invent fire and so cannot produce glass lenses with which to produce a microscope.

However, I wonder if bubbles of air, (or other gases) might do the trick. While they obviously would be a poor choice for windows and skylights and so on, could transparent bubbles of gas be used in place of glass to create a microscope-like lens acute enough to see plankton?

Comment: I would use baby transparent jelly fish of the lens variety as lenses.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In light of Monty Wild's answer suggesting bubbles won't make good lenses, here are some alternative ideas:

- **Quartz or other gemstones.** These form from volcanic activity. They have been historically used on Earth for lens-making. ([Nimrud lens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nimrud_lens), [Visby lenses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visby_lenses))
- **Eyes.** Eyes very often have lenses. It's unlikely that creatures evolved in the darkness of a subsurface ocean would have eyes. But if they want to build microscopes, perhaps they do? Lens removed from various creatures could be used for building microscopes.
- **Salt.**  Just another crystal, but one that you can grow yourself. Mastering brine-based technology would be important in a subsurface ocean anyway. So we can imagine them growing exactly the kind of crystal needed, and keeping it from dissolving.
- **Ultrasound.** Maybe they don't have eyes after all. They perceive the world through ultrasound. And they are building [acoustic microscopes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acoustic_microscopy).

Comment: "Lens removed from various creatures could be used for building microscopes." On Earth we do science by standing on the shoulders of giants - on Europa they do science by looking through the eyes of monsters.

Answer (score 18):

When we consider the [refractive index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refractive_index) of glass when compared to air for terrestrial microscopes, air has a refractive index slightly over 1, while [lens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lens) glasses have a refractive index in the range of 1.46 to 1.69.  In situations where the refractive index of a lens is greater than that of the medium in which it resides (i.e. air), a convex lens will have the effect of focusing light to a 'point' in the manner in which we are familiar, producing an enlarged image.

However, water has a refractive index of around 1.333.  If we were to use convex air bubbles (with a refractive index only slightly more than 1.0) as lenses, these air lenses wouldn't focus light as a convex lens does, but would disperse light as a concave lens does, reducing the size of the apparent image rather than enlarging it.  This doesn't mean that a microscope would be impossible, but the near impossibility in producing concave air lenses would cause considerable difficulty.

Next, we need to consider that air bubbles are typically spherical unless they are constrained to fit between two surfaces.  A spherical lens would not produce a perfect image due to [spherical aberration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_aberration).

If we were to constrain an air bubble between two solid surfaces, the distortion of the air bubble would probably not be spherical or even parabolic, and thus would be an even worse lens than a spherical bubble.  There is really no effective way of changing the shape of a good bubble lens without first being able to shape a solid lens.

Then we have to consider the composition of the air.  If the air in a bubble (or even just some of it) was able to dissolve into the surrounding water, this would lead to a situation where the size of a bubble could change over time, and thus too its refractive properties.

So, I would expect that the problems involved with using air as lenses would be extremely frustrating and unproductive.

These aquatic scientists might be better off to try to produce lenses that use ice (with a refractive index of 1.31).  The lenses wouldn't be very powerful, but they would be shapeable and a convex lens would act as we expect lenses to act.  The only problem would be keeping the lenses cold and the water warm.  Perhaps fill the ice-lens tubes with air?  That would both increase the refractive power of the lenses and isolate the frozen lenses from the warmer water.  They would still be problematic.

Comment: To save other folks from googling the obvious question: no, there aren't other gases than air that have a higher refractive index, except under *extreme* pressures (ten atmospheres might get you up to 0.03 above vacuum, where recall our target is somewhere around 0.6 above vacuum).

Comment: You can get ten atmospheres 100m under the surface of water. But now you have to look at stars through 100m of water.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, they could.

The [Leeuwenhoek microscope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antonie_van_Leeuwenhoek) used a drop of liquid as its single lens. A bubble is the opposite sense of lens as it is a sphere with a lower refractive index than the surround. If they have a collar of water-repellant material, they can trap a bubble. If they suck out some of the air, they get a concave void which will work like a lens.

For a compound microscope, you will need a much longer focal length for the eyepiece. You can use an [oil and water lens](https://www.e-consystems.com/blog/camera/technology/how-liquid-lens-cameras-work-the-ultimate-guide/). A more robust solution might use a bubble trapped between thin, transparent membranes. Both designs are commercially available.

Comment: I'd love some details on the concave bubble. The only concave bubble I can imagine is a ring, like what dolphins blow. But a bubble like a concave lens? How can that be stable?

Comment: Imagine having a tube filled with a bubble of air, so the bubble bulges out either end. Suck some air out. If the inside of the tube repels water, then the edge of the surface is stuck on the end, the surface will go flat, and then curve inwards. You could have a half-lens with a flat sheet of glass on one end.

Answer (score 4):

A bubble will be spherical. To have a lensing effect, you need to change the shape from spherical to something different. To do so you need something transparent to trap the bubble and force it to the new shape.

But that transparent thing is the same glass you have problems inventing.

A small drop of glass can act as lens, but glass has a higher refraction index than air. A small bubble of air would not work in the same way.

Comment: You could put the liquid and entire microscope inside a rotating chamber, which would result in a non-spherical bubble due to centrifugal force - this is similar to how a liquid mirror in a telescope works.

Answer (score 0):

I am sharing videos instead of research papers (that in my opinion should indicate more that it is possible given enough time and resources) because who has time to read 100+ pages. With our dry land-based technology we have already touched on how possible it is, by simply combining a couple of current technologies and some research I would definitely believe it to be possible.

I might be a little late to the party, but as most of the other answers say, if you do in fact try to use an air bubble to create a microscope, you will need to be able to transform the bubble into other shapes than the natural sphere. The natural spherical shape of a bubble is mostly created by the water pressure. Another thing that changes pressure is sound. You can create patterns with sounds: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wvJAgrUBF4w and it creates differences in pressures. Read a bit about Sonoluminescence and then imagine where we could have ended up should more research in that direction be applied. In a similar fashion, you can also use wing designs and movement in water to create lower and higher pressures. Naturally, the design of the wing will not be to create lift, but to create specific low and high water pressures. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GR_4T7le4Dg

So I would posit that you can create a sound air microscope underwater as well as a movement engine for making an underwater microscope. The sound will have the benefit of simply changing the frequency and it will be possible to increase and decrease the refractivity of the bubble created.... So it can be a very nice advanced piece of microscopic possibly eclipsing what we currently have. While the movement one can be a good starting off point for the civilisation.

Think of having a couple of composite waves that trap an air bubble and using the difference in pressure to form the bubble into a convex/concave shape that you need. Similar to acoustic levetation, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cWe3l8paA4Y. You can even do a lot of other things with sound (aka pressure waves) and water. I would think an advanced species that lives under water would give more research to solving the problems we as a species have encountered do to them permanently being surrounded by liquids. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GyT1dsY0KtA